# Pandas delete a row in a dataframe based on a value

Tags: python, pandas

I want do delete rows in a pandas dataframe where a the second column = 0

So this ...

```
  Code  Int
0    A    0
1    A    1
2    B    1
```

Would turn into this ...

```
  Code  Int
0    A    1
1    B    1
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the row you want to delete, and use [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

```
delete_row = df[df["Int"]==0].index
df = df.drop(delete_row)
print(df)
Code    Int
1   A   1
2   B   1
```

Further more. you can use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to find the row, if you know the position of the column

```
delete_row = df[df.iloc[:,1]==0].index
df = df.drop(delete_row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) in one line of code.

```
df = df.drop(df["Int"].loc[df["Int"]==0].index)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer is technically correct but the original answer is just a bit more succinct. Nevertheless, I hope you'll keep contributing here! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this as well!

```
df = df[df.Int != 0]
```