# Delete a row in pandas dataframe while using df.iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to delete the row if there is data missing in a certain column in the current row.

This is what I wrote:

```
for c, r in data.iterrows():
if (r['A'] == ""):
    data = data.drop(r)
```

But I receive the error:

> "unreadable key error"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas delete a row in a dataframe based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182464/pandas-delete-a-row-in-a-dataframe-based-on-a-value)

Comment: Though it wouldn't lead to an issue in this particular case, in general you should avoid making changes to the thing you iterate over: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346696/why-is-it-not-safe-to-modify-sequence-being-iterated-on (Also unnecessary to loop in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
data = data.drop(data[data['A'] == ''].index)
```

OR

```
data[data['A'] != ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
data[data['A'] != ""]
```

`data['A'] != ""` returns as bolean series that is True for each row where that value is not "".

Answer (score 0):

For your part identation error if not you have to refer them as NaN values.

For dropping the data from a row if having null values.
    df = df[df['Column_name'].notna()]